# onready event in sharepoint

Tags: javascript, events, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I try to call `new SP.ClientContext.get_current()` but at the time I'm doing so I get an `Cannot read property 'get_current' of undefined` error because `SP.ClientContext` is not initialized. If I call the method later everything works fine.

So I have to wait until everything in the Sharepoint UI is loaded. How to do that?

I need a js ready event similar to the jQuery [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) bot for the Sharepoint UI scripts, maybe with [SP.SOD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff410742) but I can't figure out how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are on the right track. Use ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded to call your function after sp.js and use _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push to call that function once the SharePoint page is fully loaded.

For more information, see [Javascript to display sharepoint list items on page load](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/28534/javascript-to-display-sharepoint-list-items-on-page-load).